# Elevation issue when using Azure DevOps Agent to run testcases

Tags: azure, azure-devops, user-agent

When running azure devops agent interactively to trigger test scriptsthen I am getting error message

**System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The requested operation requires elevation**

User which agent is using to trigger test cases is administrator.
Few days ago everything was working fine but somehow this error showed up and now I am not able to run test scripts.

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk anything you would like to suggest on the above question?

Comment: Hi, only test script do error? other builds are ok?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk We are implementing Azure devoops for the very first time. Due to complexity in build we are manually deploying site.I use Agent for release only. At the time of release I run test scripts.

Comment: Ans the release only run the tests? the release started and then got an error or got the error before he started?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk as soon as agent hits the file to run test cases at that time only I get such error message

Comment: The tests execute `exe` file?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk No, tests are saved in a .dll file

Comment: What the dll does? Can you check the test code?

Comment: that dll has got test cases which run as soon as dll is hit.
Browser gets opend and selenium webdirver starts its work to test UI